# App crashes very rare on start up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, crash

I have a strange problem with my app, sometimes, very rare in fact, when run on iPhone4, it crashes right at the beginning, I got the crash log, but I really can't make anything of it. I'm kind of stuck, where should I look? Here is the log:

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34c96a1c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x328ee3b4 pthread_kill + 52
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x328e6bf8 abort + 72
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x329146d4 __assert_rtn + 140
4   My App                  0x0000fb8c 0x1000 + 60300
5   My App                  0x0000fec4 0x1000 + 61124
6   My App                  0x00009ffc 0x1000 + 36860
7   CoreFoundation                  0x359c979c __invoking___ + 60
8   CoreFoundation                  0x35941436 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 102
9   My App                  0x0005f408 0x1000 + 386056
10  My App                  0x0005c9b8 0x1000 + 375224
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3593656a -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 18
12  My App                  0x000b60d4 0x1000 + 741588
13  My App                  0x000b6bc0 0x1000 + 744384
14  My App                  0x000b8c9c 0x1000 + 752796
15  UIKit                           0x35584bee -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 362
16  UIKit                           0x35584568 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 256
17  UIKit                           0x3556d30c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 292
18  UIKit                           0x3556cc4c _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5084
19  GraphicsServices                0x35350e70 PurpleEventCallback + 660
20  CoreFoundation                  0x3599da90 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
21  CoreFoundation                  0x3599f838 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
22  CoreFoundation                  0x359a0606 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
23  CoreFoundation                  0x35930ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
24  CoreFoundation                  0x35930dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
25  GraphicsServices                0x35350418 GSEventRunModal + 108
26  GraphicsServices                0x353504c4 GSEventRun + 56
27  UIKit                           0x35597d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
28  UIKit                           0x35595800 UIApplicationMain + 664
29  My App                  0x00002118 0x1000 + 4376
30  My App                  0x00002084 0x1000 + 4228
```

I was not able to find any pattern for the crash, it simply happens like maybe once in 30-40 app start-ups. What beats me, beside the fact that I don't know how the interpret the crash log, is why this happens so rare, with no apparent reason?

Comment: You are missing the symbols from your app as it seems - symbolicate that log; see http://www.goosoftware.co.uk/blog/the-symbolicator-helps-those-who-help-themselves/ for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [symbolicate](http://furbo.org/2008/08/08/symbolicatifination/) that crash log before you can see exactly which part of your code is crashing.